# ReactJS:: Issues with loading images while showing spinner

Tags: reactjs

I am pretty new to react and I am trying to do this simple task about showing spinner while the image loads. It works the way I expect it to be for the first two times i.e. the spinner loads and thereafter the image loads. But after that, the spinner keeps spinning and the image does not load. Here is the code to App.js that can included in index.js:

```
import React from "react";
import CircularProgress from "@material-ui/core/CircularProgress";

export default function App() {
  const [loaded, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState({
    src: "https://via.placeholder.com/60"
  });

  const handleClick = () => {
    setLoaded(false);
    setImage({ src: "https://picsum.photos/200/300" });
  };

  const getProgress = () => {
    console.log("-----inside getProgress", loaded);
    return (
      <CircularProgress
        color="secondary"
        style={!loaded ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <>
        <img
          src={image.src}
          alt="a placeholder"
          onLoad={() => setLoaded(true)}
          style={loaded ? { display: "inline-block" } : { display: "none" }}
        />
        {!loaded && getProgress()}
        <br />
        <a href="#" onClick={handleClick}>
          Click here
        </a>
      </>
    </div>
  );
}
```

and here is the index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

I figured why the issue is happening is because after the third time the onLoad does not set the loaded to true and therefore it keeps showing the spinner. But what baffles me is the first time the "Click here" link is clicked is very similar to clicking that link the second time and any number of times. Why then the output isn't the same? I am also looking for how can I fix this and make it even better. I have referred to a lot of material here on StackOverflow and elsewhere but I am unable to resolve this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In getProgress you are console logging the loaded variable.

```js
  const getProgress = () => {
    console.log("-----inside getProgress", loaded);
    return (
      <CircularProgress
        color="secondary"
        style={!loaded ? { display: "block" } : { display: "none" }}
      />
    );
  };
```

In JavaScript the && is the and operator, so in this line:

```js
{!loaded && getProgress()}
```

If the first operand of the and operator is true then it will evaluate the second operand which is getProgress(). But because you used !loaded you are basically saying when it is not loaded run getProgress(). And then what it logs is always going to be false because you only allow it to run when !loaded.

If you want to see what the actual value is when you press the button then you need to do:

```js
{getProgress()}
```

What is better than this is to use the React useEffect hook to watch the different values of loaded:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log(loaded);
}, [loaded]);
```

Comment: thank you for your inputs. I think I know what you moan and can log the value of the loaded state using the useEffect hook. However, I need to know what I can do to fix this.